# Pass arbitrary number of variables through multiple functions/classes/methods

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, keyword-argument

I have a class with methods that looks something like this

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, strat):
        self.strat_cls = strat
        self._genInstances()

    def _genInstances(self):
        self.strat = self.strat_cls(self.x, self.y)
```

and the strat_cls:

```
class strat1(Strat):   
    def __init__(self, x=4):
        self.x = x

    def calculate_something(self, event):
        if x > 2:
           print("hello")
```

I initialize everything by:

```
example = A(strat1)
```

When initializing I need to be able to pass an arbitrary number of arguments to the calculate_something method in the strat1 class like this:

```
example = A(strat1, x=3)
```

or

```
example = A(strat1, x=3, y=5)
```

where y will then be used further down in the calculate_something method.

How do I do that? I need to be able to pass both "new variables" and overriding the x variable. I've tried several times using *args and **kwargs, but I end up with errors.

Comment: The way I get it, most of your question is not relevant. What do you want to achieve? What did you tried? What errors did you encounter?

Comment: I might be wrong, but I think the above both answers what I want to achieve and what I have tried. I, unfortunately, don't have the errors anymore as I tried a lot of different with *args and **kwargs. I have explained a bit more in the above now. Please see if that helps, thanks.

Comment: Post some of your tries with *args and **kwargs, that is probably the right direction to go.

Comment: Why are there both Python 2 and Python 3 tags on here? The syntax for an "ideal solution" may likely vary depending on the version of Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your code with comments. The main point is you have to save the arguments in *A* and pass them to *strat* when you're initializing it.

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, strat, **strat_kwargs):
        self.strat_cls = strat
        # save kwargs to pass to strat
        self.strat_kwargs = strat_kwargs
        self._genInstances()

    def _genInstances(self):
        # init strat with kwargs
        self.strat = self.strat_cls(**self.strat_kwargs)


class strat1(Strat):
    def __init__(self, x=4, y=None):
        # save x and y
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def calculate_something(self, event):
        # use self.x here
        if self.x > 2:
            print("hello")
```